# Parametic question, with augmented matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> [image]

I'm very confused on what to do and don't know where to start, and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no blanks.

The solution to your system is all vectors of the form $(-s+2,-2s-1,s)$.  It is the set $\{s(-1,-2,1)+(2,-1,0):s\in\Bbb R\}$.  (This is an affine space, but not a vector space.)

As is always the case in this situation, we have a particular solution plus all elements of the solution space of the associated homogeneous system.